# NGRX - Run Function After Every Effect

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Is it possible to have some sort of 'callback function' or watcher to an NGRX Effect? The use case is, I'm trying to persist state across browser refresh. I'd like to call my cache service to save the app state after each effect has run. Currently, I'm doing this by adding this to every effect:

```
tap(() => setTimeout(() => this.cacheService.saveAppState()))
```

It feels like there should be a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. You can implement `OnRunEffects` on the effects classes. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderStoreEffects implements OnRunEffects {
  // Resolves to either QueryCompleted or QueryFailed
  @Effect()
  queryOrdersFromProduct$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(...);

  // Resolves to either QueryCompleted or QueryFailed
  @Effect()
  queryOrdersFromWorkCenter$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(...);

  constructor(...) {}

  ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects$: Observable<EffectNotification>) {
    return resolvedEffects$.pipe(tap(effect => console.log({ effect })));
  }
}
```

The `resolvedEffects$` observable emits **every time** that an effect in the `OrderStoreEffects` class is executed and resolved.

The emitted values look like this:

[image]

Which gives you some further possibilities to apply filters or other logic.

For more information about the `OnRunEffects` interface, check [the docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#onruneffects)

Comment: isn't this for initial effects resolve&subscribe to store and not for every action going into effects?

Comment: I didnt understood your question, could you please rephrase?

Comment: i thought this is used to control when `@Effect` is added to pipeline. so, registered, resolved & subscribed to the store. not for every run as reaction to actions.

Comment: Oh gotcha. No, I actually mentioned that point as its relevant for OPs use case.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was searching all morning and could not find this method!

Answer (score 1):

you don't need anything special. Write separate effect with function you've shown and just don't filter action type in it but go directly:

`this.$actions.pipe(/* your logic here */)`

so that will run for all actions.

now you can have `withLatestFrom` to get current state and do whatever you need with it.

[UPDATE]

This is something i'd not implement in effects but in `canDeactivate` router guards.

Comment: this would execute then on every action, which is not desirable.

Comment: The actions are calling every effect. You get to the effect by doing this on every action.

Comment: yes - but i do not want this specific effect to run on every action. piping on the action without filtering would trigger this function call on every action which isn't necessary and could affect performance

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe to ur effect for example:

```
this.store.dispatch(
        new YourActionEffect()
      );

 this.yourEffects.yourfunction.subscribe(
  (
    action:
      | yourActions.action1
      | yourActions.action2
  ) => {
    if (action === YourActionTypes.ACTION1) {
      //when action1 is fire
    }
    else {
      //when action2 is fire
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'd be better off using effects for that.

What you really need is a hook to be warned after every store update. And this can be managed with meta reducers.

Hopefully, there's already a library that handles all of that for you!

Take a look here https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage